# How to differentiate between "true" and boolean true in YamlDotNet

Tags: c#, yamldotnet

I have a class with a `dynamic` member. When the value is a boolean, it's serialized as `true / false` which deserializes to a string. Is this an issue with YamlDotNet, or if not, how can I force it to serialize as `true` rather than `"true"`?

This is a class I'm trying to serialize

```
public class Field : IField
{
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public FieldFormatterEnum FormatterType { get; set; }
    public dynamic Value { get; set; }
    public dynamic DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public dynamic FormattedValue { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The typed deserializer method:

```
    public T DeserializeObject<T>(string input)
    {
        T o;
        using (var tr = new StringReader(input))
        {
            o = new Deserializer().Deserialize<T>(tr);
        }
        return o;
    }
```

Field is in a `List` in another class which is being serialized / deserialized.

---

Update: After looking at the serialized output, YamlDotNet outputs the serialized boolean as `true` and not `"true"`. So.. I'm guessing it's a problem with the deserialization code in YamlDotNet?

Comment: Could you provide a few lines of code ?

Comment: and your deserialization routine ?

Answer (score 0):

For serialization, you could create a getter-only property as a `bool` that has the value you want:

```
public bool ValueAsBool
{
    get
    {
        bool outValue = false;
        if(Value is string)
        {
            bool.TryParse((string)Value, out outValue);
            return outValue;
        }
        return outValue;
    }
}
```

Ultimately, when working with `dynamic`s you will be throwing some type information away, and you shouldn't expect to be able to recover all of it properly.

Comment: it should be a tryparse surely? But, what if the user does actually want the string "true" and sets the dynamic ```Value``` to "true"?

Comment: definitely. unless he's always expecting it to be `bool` (which is unlikely if he's using a `dynamic`...)

Answer (score 0):

I've just set up a simple test like:

```
class Foo
{
    public dynamic V { get; set; }
}

var f1 = new Foo(){V = 5};    
var tw2 = new StringWriter();
new Serializer().Serialize(tw2, f1);
var tr2 = new StringReader(tw2.ToString());
var f_1 = new Deserializer().Deserialize<Foo>(tr2);
```

... and `V` is deserialized as `"5"`. The default type to deserialize to is `string`